# Navigation element remains highlighted in Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

After clicking on either right or left in this carousel, the button remains darker, even after you mouse off the elelemnt. I assume the reason is some sort of visited state, but looking at the CSS, I don't see anything relevant. Is there any way to prevent that effect?

I've [written a JSFiddle to demonstrate it](https://jsfiddle.net/waynn/n5k2f52k/2/), and copied the HTML below.

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='carousel slide' data-interval='false' id='product-image-carousel'>
      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <center class='carousel-inner'>
        <div class='active item'>
            <img alt='...' src='http://placehold.it/300x200'>
        </div>
        <div class='item'>
          <img alt='...' src='http://placehold.it/300x200'>
        </div>
      </center>
      <!-- Controls -->
      <a class='left carousel-control' data-slide='prev' href='#product-image-carousel' role='button'>
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left'></span>
      </a>
      <a class='right carousel-control' data-slide='next' href='#product-image-carousel' role='button'>
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right'></span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- Carousel -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[jsfiddle Update](https://jsfiddle.net/n5k2f52k/9/)

```
.carousel-control:focus {
    outline: none;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.carousel-control:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick workaround: Overwrite bootstrap's css.

```
.carousel-control:hover, 
.carousel-control:focus {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: .9;
  filter: alpha(opacity=90);
}
```

Remove completely the :focus selector

Answer (score 0):

You can use this workaround:

```
$(".carousel-control").focus(function(event){
    $(this).blur();
});
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Simply fix this with css , Decrease the opacity to this `.carousel-control:hover, .carousel-control:focus` classess , apply the below code your `fiddle` or your `page` you can see the difference , Thanks

```
 #product-image-carousel a {
   outline: none !important; /* this will remove the outline when we click the anchor tag */
 }
 .carousel-control:hover, .carousel-control:focus {
   opacity: 0.5; /* this will remove the darker color on focus and hover */
 }
```